# Set Applicationname when using Postgres ODBC driver

Tags: postgresql, odbc

How can I set the application name when connection to Postgres with the psqLODBC driver?

You get the application name from pg_stat_activity.application_name.

I tried different Parameters in the connection string.

`APP=...;` `application_name=...;` `APP_NAME=...` in all different variations.

Nothings works and pg_stat_activity.application_name always returns an empty string.

Comment: Given that the [documentation](https://odbc.postgresql.org/docs/config-opt.html) does not list a property for that: you could run `set application_name = 'doev';` after the connection is established

Comment: No, the documentation has no hint. And I have no idea, how I can use 'set' in my environment.

Comment: It's a SQL statement, run it like any other SQL statement.

Comment: thank you. After I found out, how to open a odbc connection by vba-code, I could use your solution. I think I will delete this question in some time.

Comment: `application_name=...` would be the correct syntax in a regular connection string , but those semicolons and upper-case letters must be a windows thing - what name are you trying to set?

Comment: @doev: no reason to delete your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have established a connection in your application, you can run a SQL statement to change the application_name dynamically.

```
set application_name = 'doev';
```

You run that just like any other statement (that does not return a result) with your programming language. But remember if you have turned off autocommit in your connection, you need to `commit` that `SET` statement. If you are running in autocommit mode, that is not necessary.